# What installertype to use with Chocolatey to install a powershell module?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I have a set of Powershell modules that I would like to have managed with Chocolatey. It is only the Module folder that I want to deploy. What $installerType should I use? Does anyone have a suggestion of what approach should be considered when installing a Powershell module?

Comment: What is `$installertype`? Is that a parameter to a function or cmdlet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to guess that the `$installertype` parameter that you are referring to is one of the input parameters associated with the `Install-ChocolateyPackage` command (or similar) which is documented [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyPackage).  This helper method is really only used when you are installing an application using either an MSI or an EXE, which you instruct Chocolatey to download for you from the internet.

When installing a PowerShell Module, it is unlikely that you will have an EXE or an MSI to do the install for you.  More likely, you are going to have a zip file that you need to extract into the PowerShell Modules folder, or a straight up *.psm1 file that you want to place there.  In which case, a helper method such as `Install-ChocolateyZipPackage` which you can find documented [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyZipPackage) would probably be better.

There are a number of Chocolatey Packages on [chocolatey.org](http://chocolatey.org/) that already show how you can install a PowerShell Module.  I would suggest that you take a look at these packages, for instance:

- [PowerShell DSC Modules](http://chocolatey.org/packages/DSC.PowerShellCommunity)
- [poshgit](http://chocolatey.org/packages/poshgit)
- [Posh-hg](http://chocolatey.org/packages/Posh-HG)
- [Pester](http://chocolatey.org/packages/pester)

Which will give you some ideas about the different ways that you can do the install.  If you haven't already, do `choco install nugetpackageexplorer` and then use this tool to view the contents of each of the above packages, as shown here:

[image]

and then hopefully you will be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that doc page when searching, and it is actually out of date wrt the source code which calls it "fileType".

Comment: Ah, even better catch! Looks like we need to do a review of the documentation to make sure that it is up to date.  Could I ask that you raise an issue to cover this problem [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/new) so that it doesn't get forgotten about?  Cheers!

Comment: Ok, done! Also, it'll be awesome when WMF 5 is released with support for finding/installing PS modules directly from nuget and built-in support for chocolatey.

Comment: Agreed, there are a couple systems out there already that try to solve this problem, i.e. poshcode, and psget, but a fully supported implementation from Microsoft will certainly make things easier going forward.

Comment: Thanks @GaryEwanPark. The cited packages demonstrate exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that you got it worked out! Happy Chocolating! :-)

Comment: @mikez what "FileType" did you end up using with your powershell module

Answer (score 0):

RE the second part of your question - an approach for managing & deploying powershell modules using Chocolatey - I've found this article to be very useful:

http://patrickhuber.github.io/2015/03/17/creating-reusable-powershell-modules-with-psget-and-chocolatey.html

It uses PsGet to install the powershell module, and the whole approach is clean and well-structured.

If you go with this approach, the `$installerType` parameter is unnecessary.